# Why was my this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderators, answers

I posted an answer to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/why-did-sri-ramanuja-refuse-to-hail-shiva-what-was-the-need-to-prove-that-vishn) question but it was deleted by one moderator citing that "this does not answer the question".

> This does not answer the specific question about Ramanujacharya's
>   reasons, so I'm deleting your answer for the time being. If you want
>   to edit your answer so that it answers the question, edit it and flag
>   me to undelete it

What is funny,is that the OP had already  accepted my answer.So,needless to say that i **answered his query correctly**.

In any case,

**1)What kind of edits are expected from my side?**

& **2) When the question asker has accepted the answer why should a Mod interfere and delete it by citing the aforementioned reasons?Any other reasons would have been reasonable**

And the main question that was in OP's mind was "Are Shiva & Vishnu one ,Should we or should we not differentiate between them?" which i properly answered by citing scriptures.And OP proved my point by accepting the answer.

**Update**-I have edited my answer now.Right now it looks like a good partial answer with ample support from the Scriptures.

**Update # 2-** The concerned(Main) question is now edited in a way so that my answer will look as "not answering the question". Those parts to which i was replying to were now removed.So,my this present question is not relevant any more.

Comment: [Partial answers](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/500/2995) are valid and shouldn't be deleted. But you shot yourself in the foot there by selecting an answer that says comments should be used for writing partial answers :) Whether OP accepted your answer or not, you did not answer the title question about Ramanuja's action or view. I agree with the mod that you didn't really answer the main question, but I didn't think it should be deleted. I'd suggest put a disclaimer at the beginning saying "This is a partial answer; it doesn't answer the title question" and then flag to undelete.

Comment: @sv."Not answering the question" are not  reasons enough for deletion on this site and you know that..And how to decide which r OP's main questions?...i answered few of the questions that are found in the body of it..let the asker decide whether i answered his Q or not..and in this case he accepted ,my answer..so he was happy with it..after that the mod has no business in delting it by citing the reasons which he did..And in any case the answer was edited by me and its first line now says "Here is my partial answer..."

Comment: Not answering the question is indeed reason enough for deletion on this site.  And the fact that the OP clicked accept doesn't mean anything.  We enforce standards of quality on answers because answers do not just benefit the questioner, they are supposed to benefit readers in general.  If a reader Google searches "Why did Ramanuja refuse to pray to Shiva?" and he finds a Hinduism Stackexchange link, he should have an expectation that the page will give him the answer to his question.

Comment: Now if the OP wants to edit the question so that it only asks about whether Vishnu and Shiva are the same and doesn't ask about Ramanujacharya, then your answer wouldn't be deleted, although then the question would probably be closed as a duplicate of the many other questions on the site that discuss whether Vishnu and Shiva are one.  Bottom line: if you want to post an answer about whether Vishnu and Shiva are one, your best bet is to post it in one of those other questions.  But if you want to edit your answer so that it answers the question about Ramanujacharya, I'd be happy to undelete it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan **And the fact that the OP clicked accept doesn't mean anything** Really?!!..i thought sites such as this r all  about the questioner and whether he is happy with the answer or not...So,don't want me to believe this nonsense.. **We enforce standards of quality on answers because answers do not just benefit the questioner, they are supposed to benefit readers in general. If a reader Google searches "Why did Ramanuja refuse to pray to Shiva?"** We who??..Don't bother about such things..i don't think they are part of a mod's job

Comment: You can not interfere unduly btween the questioner and an answerer unless it is obviously required...And don't even try to set standards..you are not leraned enuf to decide which is good or bad on a hinduism site..its simply not that easy..You certainly shud not bother about those landing from Google on here..let them do their own thinking..they obviously know that this is just a site..anything written on here as answers are not gospel truths.

Comment: @Rickross Enforcing the quality standards of the site are definitely part of a mod's job.  Stackexchange sites are not just random free-for-alls like Yahoo answers, they're meant to create a knowledge base on a particular subject.  The goal for Hinduism Stackexchange is that it should develop a reputation that if you search for any Hinduism topic, you'll find a high-quality, well-sourced answer about it on the site that answers your question.

Comment: That was a partial answer...was accepted by the user...was not a low quality answer by any means..shud be undeleted ...thats it....what is more  to discuss here.??...

Comment: @Rickross Like I said, if the OP edits the question so that it's only about unity of Vishnu and Shiva and not about Ramanujacharya, or if you edited your answer so it is about Ramanujacharya, I'd be happy to undelete your answer.  But in its current state it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan And as i said..stop giving stupid excuses..everyone is seeing what u are doing here...If u are serious about maintaining site quality then start doing that by deleting ur  **plainly wrong**  answers like [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8287/4732)..Do u even know what is Shakti Gaanapty?? ..What about those visitors who land on such answers luking from Google ?Aren't they getting wrong ideas??

Comment: @Rickross please [Be Nice](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Sorry Pandya..i'm outta of here...bye..

Comment: @Rickross Let's distinguish two things.  Maintaining the standards of the site is the job of mods.  But determining whether an answer is factually correct or not is the job of the community, through voting.  Now I don't think my Shakti Ganapati answer is incorrect, but if it is I'm happy to correct it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan So if u can't decide whether a particular answer is wrong or right how r u supposed maintain site quality...?To maintain the quality of site like the way u are mentioning wud require appointments of only verified experts as Mods..Do we do that ?No of course..and what wrong messages wud one landing from google on that answer wud get?I have not spoken about Ramanuja at all...So whats ur apprehension all about.? To know that Shiva and Vishnu are actually one is a great thing..Only blessed ones are capable of knowing that..

Comment: @Rickross Like I said, two different things should be distinguished. There's the issue of whether an answer meets basic standards of quality, e.g whether it answers the question and whether it cites sources. That is what is moderation about. Assuming it meets those basic standards, then it can be voted on by the community who decide whether they think the answer is right or wrong. Moderation and voting serve different purposes.  In any case, I have no problem with you posting an answer asserting that Vishnu and Shiva are one, as long as you post such an answer on a question that is about that.

Comment: Related: [Upvoted and accepted answer deleted by moderator](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/559/upvoted-and-accepted-answer-deleted-by-moderator)

Comment: @iammilind That answer was deleted citing "lacking citations "as reasons..In my case the reasons cited was" was not answering the question" which was not the case as i was definitely answering the question,partially to be precise..

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I was definitely answering the previous Q..no one can deny that..Now the Q is intentionally edited in a way that makes my answer luk "not answering the Q"...In any case,i was not answering the Q in its current form at all..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer **doesn't deserve deletion**, at least the way it happened.

Before deleting this answer, the "delete bulldozer" has to run over so many other answers, which are indeed bad.

<sub>BTW, don't take reputation too seriously. It's just an activity & agreement indicator. Similarly, "Accepting an answer" is not necessarily a good reason of "un-deletable answer". Imagine, if a person creates a dummy account & posts a question. Then the same person answers with real account & is later accepted from dummy account. The accepted answer here can contain complete misinformation as well.</sub>

---

The answer **does require moderator attention** due to the language used with implied sarcasm (some may call it "rudeness"). Not sure, if Mod discussed the concerns with you before deletion. See some of the sentences:

- "Some deluded person said ...   "
  ==> Not right. Wise persons don't call others deluded.
- "... that is the most blatant lie i have ever seen."
  ==> Too Extreme way to express disagreement.
- "... or he is just ignorant."
  ==> Inappropriate language by calling names.
- "... opposite of what he said."
  ==> Pinpointing someone specific in not so good light.
- "Now , if a so called devotee of Vishnu(or anyone for that matter)..."
  ==> Sarcasm again. Also, you are isolating yourself from the liberal Vaishnava-s as well.
- "...who are preaching such hatred are all sinners"
  ==> Being too judgemental. Remember, people criticised Krishna, when he asked everyone to stop praying to Indra, who was considered the god of that era. Never say "never".

"Hinduism" (including this SE) should be about giving way to all kinds of thinking, praising & criticism. Provided that the things are presented in a parliamentary language. You should have expressed your points in an acceptable tone (or criticism), such as Tezz's answer in below post, which also gives POV of all gods:
[How were the Trimurthi born?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/237/1049)

Or remember your own answer :-)
[What do scriptures say about using swear or abusive words for cursing people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15460/1049)

"Abusive language" is not limited to curses only. A person can abuse another, without using a single curse word.

---

**IMO, remove the sarcasm part from your answer & flag it for undeletion.**

<sub>Since the Qn is re-edited twice in such a way by the mod, that it doesn't include the query you are answering. Hence your current post as it is, may not be undeleted, even if the language is improved.</sub>

Comment: 1)If i was asked that by removing what u call" abusive languages" from my answer will make it fit for un-deletion then i wud have probably done that...If u see my Q ,one of my questions is "what kind of edits...?2)  **Sin sin sin sin... **  were not stated by me at all..i just post what scriptures state on a topic and if i'm not mistaken then one(while answering) is supposed to do exactly that..For eg abortion is considered as a grave sin by Scriptures and i don't have any different opinion on that..

Comment: @Rickross, (1) If not discussed with you the, that part of Mod job was missed. But you can still remove the controversial language & mark for undeletion. It will give better credibility to your case, IMO. (2) May be you missed my point. By "sin, sin...", I was referring to pattern of many of your recent answers & not any particular one. Your "sin" related answers were upvoted by many. Means those were noticed & taken seriously. (Slowly people start looking you as a judge subconsciously). So When you point your "sin sword" to a person, he/she may get offended. But let's drop this as off-topic.

Comment: Milind if a Q is asking whether masturbation or abortion or adultery are sins or not and if i know what the Scriptures say on those acts then it can not be that i won't post answers..I  always will..

Comment: milind,Ok..but now i can not flag and ask for un-deletion because the Q is now altered so as to remove those portions to which i was specifically answering..now my answer is not answering the (current edited) Q.

Comment: @Rickross, I have re-edited the post to bring back the old Qn from the main post. Now with a banner of "partial answer", you may re-edit your answer and flag for the undeletion. But then you are morally liable to change your opinion in this post: [Are partial answers considered valid answers?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/500/1049). BTW, I have upvoted the answer you had accepted. But I do understand that, in philosophical sites, often people don't have full answers. Moreover, sometimes the partial answers are capable to answer fully due to their context.

Comment: milind,thanks for pointing to that question of mine..i have selected a different answer now which says partial answers shud be allowed...I myself have posted several answers which are partial..and it is often we find that one question having a lot of questions in it..

Comment: Regarding the current Ramanuja Q the answer is quite obvious since he was a Vishnu devotee no one have any right to convert him into some other devotee..its anyone's fundamental right to choose one's Ishta Devata and it is no one's business to interfere with it..But ramanuja himself supposedly [forced](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/ramanujacharyas-brother/15637#15637) Vishnu on his brother when the later turned towards Shiva..So ,i think he got what he gave..

Comment: @Rickross, sorry. The Qn is now reedited by the mod almost to it's previous version. That doesn't include the Qn, you answered. Hence now it may not be possible for you to flag for undeletion. You need to overcome it.

Comment: Both the answers confirm that deleting the answer was wrong.That is also my view.But since i'm  able to select only one among the two i have selected one.

Answer (score 6):

I think your answer more focuses on the comment (rather than the actual question) that you've mentioned in the answer:

> Some deluded person said in comments **"one who views Vishnu and Shiva as same has repeated birth/deaths."**
>
> Now,that is the most blatant lie i have ever seen.
>
> I don't know if he had said that intentionally or he is just ignorant.
>
> In any case, what the Shastras say is just the opposite of what he said.You will know once you see the following quotes(in particular the quote#3):

So, the nature of your answer is "Proving Vishnu(Hari) and Shiva(Har) same by scriptural support." Whereas the question is mainly about :

> - Why did he refuse to hail Shiva? After all he is also a god.
> - What is the need here for Ramanuja to prove that Vishnu is the one true God?

Your answer looks missing the above main aspect of the question which is emphasized by the title of question. In other words ***your answer has nothing to do with Ramanujacharya whom the question is about!***

---

Though I'm not saying that you're wrong regarding the question as the thing from question:

> Aren't Shiva and Vishnu two gods of the same Brahman?
>
> In my view, Hari and Shiva are the same. Please enlighten me.

Created a ground for discussion/views/opinions and that's why I think you're inspired to prove the oneness of Shiva and Vishnu with scriptural support!

---

That's all I can say about the reason for deletion of your post. Discussing with the respective moderator (here Keshav Srinivasan) may help you to find out justification or the actual reason as a moderator.

---

And yes, you're right:

If the answer covers some of the topics of question I.e It is partially answer the question
and/<s>or</s> If the answer is accepted by questioner,

Then I think it is not a good idea to delete the answer. Rather you should be commented asking for including missing topics instead of directly deleting the answer without a good/reasonable reason. /cc @KeshavSrinivasan

---

Update-1: Question is closed as primarily opinion based.
Update-2: Question is fixed and reopened. Your answer doesn't cover the question at all.

Comment: 1-Pandya,thanks for ur answer.If u see,there are actually 3 questions in the body that are marked out by black dots.I can't  assume which ones of them r the main questions...u considered the last 2 and i the first one viz-**Aren't Shiva and Vishnu two gods of the same Brahman?**..As to why Ramanuja behaved in a certain way  can't be answered atleast by me so i chose the one which can be answered by me..So,its a partial answer..and by accepting my answer the asker proved that i was addressing his main question only..

Comment: 2-**should not consider/take him as general person like us and criticize on him.** i have never criticised any particular person in my answer.... **Now , if a so called devotee of Vishnu(or anyone for that matter) has ill feelings towards Shiva** ..It was actually Sri Krishna who described the fates of those who has ill feeling towards Shiva..i only quoted him there from a Purana..so if u are to blame someone in that context then that shud be Krishna himself and not me..

Comment: 3-In any case deleting an answer which is accepted by showing"not answering the question" as reasons is weird..might have been acceptable if some other reasons were cited..

Comment: @Rickross main topic as per the title of the question. I've just edited the answer. And I wasn't aware of acceptable of your answer by questioner.

Comment: **And I wasn't aware of acceptable of your answer by questioner.**-Ok,yes my answer was accepted almost immediately i posted it..so quite natural to guess that he was very happy with that..deleting such an answer citing "not quite answering the question" is just absurd... **main topic as per the title of the question** ..well that may be generally true but not always the case..take for example [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16035/how-the-navagrahas-came-to-existence/16041#16041)  question..

Comment: Here the title is having one Q & the body is having more different Qs..and i actually answered only those in the body without answering the one in the title..and as u can see the questioner accepted  my answer and also posted that he considered my answer as "great"..so in  this case the main Qs were there in the body and not in title..so u never know ..let the user who is asking himself decide that..

Comment: Also i used a comment by an unidentified user (in the answer)only because it provided a nice build-up for my answer.

Comment: "f the answer is accepted by questioner

Then I think it is not a good thing to delete the answer. Rather you should be commented asking for including missing topics instead of directly deleting the answer without a good/reasonable reason"--thanks for accepting the truth..

Comment: [Discuss](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33750588#33750588)

Comment: **Update-2: Question is fixed and reopened. Your answer doesn't cover the question at all.** As i have said many times before that i was only answering the Q partially..now if someone intentionally remove those portions from the Q,to which i was replying then nothing can be done atleast  by me..To the earlier Q my answer was valid and as u have said in the answer it shudn't have been deleted....In anycase ,initially i felt i shud leave this site for ever because i never like to be be a part of a site/forum where unjust and biased mods are there,but later thought "ok let me stick on.".

Comment: **Update-1: Question is closed as primarily opinion based.** As i have shown that the previous Q can verily be answered by citing from Scriptures..so it was not opinion based IMO..The present Q,in contrast,does not luk like a good Hinduism question to me..

Comment: @Rickross Yes, I agree that your was partially answer according to earlier question. But some questions needed to be fixed. Your answer should be commented to improve instead of directly deleting as question is fixed later. But now there is no point of discussing. Sorry.

Comment: @Rickross Let community decided the best nature of question. If you're sure that question shouldn't be edited then discuss it separately.

Comment: i have never said that whether the Q shud be edited or not..i just said after the edit my answer is not all answering the Q..thts understandable because my answer was to the original Q ..

Comment: @Rickross you've said that "i felt i shud leave this site". My suggestion is better to forgot this issue and start contributing again with fresh positive mind/energy. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you..........

Comment: Both the answers confirm that deleting the answer was wrong.That is also my view.But since i'm only able to select  one among the two i have selected one.