# Should we change at least one of our current moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators, answers

### Background

This question could have been another '*Why was my answer deleted?*', as recently one of my [answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16359/1049) got deleted, which was answering the question properly with scriptures. Neither did the moderator give time nor will it help even if I press this issue further. So this post is **not** about '*Why was my answer deleted?*' but the bigger issue I discuss below.

### The Main Issue

Historically, the moderators here have hardly responded or shown any interest to address such issues. E.g. In past, I had brought my another deleted answer to Mod's chat room. Which neither did receive proper justification nor the attention it required. You can see the detailed account in this [meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/513/1049).
Even if they undelete my answer, that's not going to solve the long term problem. Because **unless they understand objectivity of when to delete** an answer & when not to, people will keep complaining here.

Not that SE has never thought about new moderators in Hinduism. In mid-November I got an email asking if I'm interested in becoming a Mod. See [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34172287#34172287) for more details.

### Question

Regardless of any other user becoming moderator, do you feel that we need a change in leadership or direction, on how things are done on Hinduism.SE?

If you can't answer the above question or comment on it, then kindly **upvote** this post if you agree or **downvote** if you disagree.

[Here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderators) you may find some of the earlier unresolved complaints. Similar question was asked before as well: [Change the moderators of Hinduism SE Site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/1049).

---

#### Why do I feel there's "unfair practices" of moderation in Hinduism.SE?

==> Example: My above mentioned answer or [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11246/1049) are not falling under the "delete criteria" of `not an answer` -- mentioned either in this [local meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/314/1049) or this [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/163449).
Instead of deleting unsourced answer as mentioned in [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/114513/search-comments?SearchQuery=cite%20sources), **they** target regular users who put proper answers. Proper justifications are not given.

#### Why do I use word "they"?

==> The other mods might be good on their own. But when unfair deletion or decision happens from particular mod, they support it by remaining passive & not reversing the decision. This can be considered as indirect support.

Comment: To be honest, I would like to close the question. Tell me seriously, rent vs buying stuff? Can you share a link with me where our Hindu scriptures explain about buying and renting.. 

Also, can I ask this question? - Should I buy games from Steam or I should get the CD's s on rent? What does scriptures have to say about this?

Comment: P.S Sorry to say this but your answer is totally incorrect. Also, we should stop shaming moderators in public just as I commented on a thread previously where I told that we should stop shaming other people by mentioning their names. If you have any issue with any of the moderator or a user, you should contact SE team and they will take care of it. Also, lately I am seeing that you want to change moderators, mind if I ask you that you that whom you would like to see as our next moderator?

Comment: @Mr.Alien, But the other Mod feels [otherwise](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/705/i-want-to-ask-a-question-on-home-buying-vs-renting-how-should-i-frame-a-valid/706#comment2438_705). Even [I too suggested](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/706/1049) that the Qn can be closed due to its very nature. To avoid getting it closed, I edited **only title**: "Hinduism on place of staying". But answered the Qn listed in it. However the title was reverted & my answer was deleted. There are no strong reasons to be Deleting the answer whatsoever.

Comment: @Mr.Alien, why don't you put an answer about what part do you find incorrect in my answer? Then let's discuss if it should be downvoted or deleted. Where have I taken any moderator's name? There is nothing on publicly shaming them. I would like to see a moderator, who is neither passive nor on long leaves nor intervening in targeting users nor unfair. Not sure if SE team wake up so easily on single user request. For example I can't present this case, if this post remains mostly downvoted. In such case, I am wrong in change of Mods. Regarding deletion of answer, I don't want to take it further.

Comment: I made some edits for readability-sake. Upvoted for the title question.

Comment: @iammilind SE team cares about every single user, feel free to contact them please.

Comment: Mr.Alien, in past I had complained something in Philosophy.SE to the team, but didn't receive any response. Besides, after being offered possible moderatorship, again didn't receive follow up response. Hence I assume that they want solid case. Presently with these many downvotes, my case is not stronger enough. Lets see how many upvotes are received after a while. If not substantial then, I will stand corrected on this issue. @sv.Thanks for edits, the Qn makes more sense now. I have been on mobile for last few hours since before this Qn. :-)

Comment: No SE community asked so many questions to remove a mod. Either there is really something wrong going on which isn't being highlighted or it is just targetting a particular mod, which as I am aware is doing a great job.

Comment: I think there should be a new moderator addition to others. I think current moderators are busy to handle pending reviews, pending flags. As @Ankitsharma is busy in moderating other site too, There should be new one helping the current three. I am not saying ankit sharma is inactive. He also answers some problems. Also my short comments get deleted. I don't know why. Anyways I don't care about them.

Comment: @SreeCharan Those short harmless comments are all deleted by Ankit sharma if i'm not wrong..Even i was irked many a times..because i don't feel its part of their jobs to intervene without any need and delete polite comments that mite build friendship between 2 users..And they were not just "thanks" comments..in those cases the Mod will argue either upvote or don't say just thanks..there was one comment i remember which was like this-"1000 upvotes for this answer :)" ..it was deleted ..

Comment: now can a user not express his gratitude/happiness/whatever even after he had upvoted the post?None can vouch that one upvote and that comment convey exactly the same message..I don't think that such unnecessary moderation is needed or that it helps anybody's cause..

Comment: The answer was bad,incorrect etc but IMO shd not have been deleted..It can't be said that the answerer was not trying to answer the question at all..It is just that his limited knowledge of Scriptures or wrong understanding of Scriptures led him astray..I was of the opinion that such Qs can be or will be answered in the Dharma Shastras,but i was unable to find anything..

Comment: Some particular Hindu sect or sects are known to be extremely fanatic..there is no doubt in this..These are verified over the years..Now in a Hinduism website the last thing i wud want is to have someone belonging to one of those sects, as the main decision making mod Its impossible for them to make unbiased decisions without being motivated by their beliefs and prejudices..So,unless we have someone else having a equal say in all matters i'm apprehensive in having such single sectarian Mod for a site like this.,

Comment: .Mistakes can be tolerated but biased decisions made intentionally  on sectarian prejudices are not tolerable..My main apprehension is regarding that point..

Comment: Milind actually answers the question .His answer is-Any of them...He then cite BG' slokas to prove his point..Now here's where he faltered..BG is basically a philosophical discourse..It was the need of the hour..to make Arjuna ready for the war by hook or by crook..But the Q in hand is not exactly a philosophical one..There r 1000s and more valid Hiduism Qs that can't be answered citing BG..This is for milind to understand..But without doubt he was answering the Q..IMO the answer shd be restored..Let the users then decide the correctness(or incorrectness) of it by voting..

Comment: And i don't think that sv's Q is off-topic..i have upvoted it..In sites like this users can't decide for sure whether a Q is off or on topic unless either its too obvious or till they see an answer which cites scriptures to answer it precisely..

Comment: Don't we deserve change in moderation?" Yes,I genuinely feel that one mod shd be removed..Because i don't think he can change himself and refrain from taking unjust decisions when the need arise..But how is that possible?What is the process of choosing Mods here?

Comment: @Rickross, We haven't graduated yet, hence we may not have elections. For now, they are chosen with selection directly by SE team. If moderator policies are not likable, then it can be complained to SE team as discussed in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/163449). But that doesn't work always as I written to Mr.Alien above. To gauge, what other members feel, I have started this meta post. If community doesn't feel change in moderatorship, then few of the "targetted users" can't do much. Idea behind this meta post is that, we don't want to keep coming on meta for deleted posts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50197/discussion-on-question-by-iammilind-should-we-change-at-least-one-of-our-current).

Comment: iammilind, @Rickross use [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198/handling-situations) room for further discussions.

Comment: @iammilind "To graduate" means what for a site?

Comment: @Rickross, you may refer [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/163449) to learn about health of an SE site. Besides, you may also visit the chatroom created by Pandya above. Personally I am clear minded about deletion on any post. e.g. deletion has to be objective. For this site, objectives are set as: "address the Qn, cite the sources". But in chatroom I failed to explain: "Objective vs Subjective". Apparently most of the people agree with Mod's decision about my deleted post in particular & moderation in general. Until ppl support Mod's actions, we can't do much. Peace. :-)

Comment: @iammilind Ok..So asking a lot questions is actually a good thing..I think sv is quite eager for a graduation and an election , & that's y he is asking a lot of questions these days :)

Comment: @Rickross you're right, I'm trying to post some Q's once in a while to increase the Qn count also. See our stats on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism). For our site it says: "10 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users keep coming back." But I try to avoid asking 'unanswerable' Q's :P because the "% answered" then goes down due to such Q's.

Comment: @TheDestroyer at-least mods can't be blamed for the close vote ;)

Comment: So are we going to see any changes any time soon?

Comment: Here are my two bits. I have had some issues with the moderators but I understand that comes with the job. I have no disrespect for the moderators. Infact, I am thankful to them for playing their part in maintaining this group. Having said that, it may be a good idea to bring in some fresh blood. Just change for the sake for the freshness. Also, assuming that people are available to take up that mantle and are willing to spend their time, energy and effort to do this job.

Comment: This is a really unhealthy way to raise the issue. If y'all are ever gonna have clear policies for answer deletion, you gotta be able to discuss them here without it being a "trial" for one side or the other. You know the moderator's rationale because he stated it in a comment when deleting - he may well be wrong, but you're not giving him credit for that, nor are you willing to debate the rationale, thus even if you get your wish and the mod team changes this will just happen again with someone else. Waste of time for everyone.

Comment: @Shog9, Probably you are saying so because you don't have the context of ongoing issues in this site. It will be better, if you can refer earlier Qns in the same tag. The policy of this site is: "if post attempts to answer, preferably with scriptures then it's valid". But this policy is violated & answers are deleted on some targeted users by the main Mod. Upon attempting to resolve issues via chat or meta, the justice is denied with wrongful arguments. It will be wasteful if you install a "yes man" or passive Mod again. Give this community a chance to select its own Mod & then see.

Comment: If you want a chance to elect your own moderators, you have to build a functional site. If you want to build a functional site, you have to be able to discuss policy with each other. If you want to discuss policy with each other, you have to be open and honest about what's happening. You referenced MrAlien's answer, but ignored the closing paragraph; you accused another moderator but ignored the rationale he gave. How are we supposed to take any of this seriously if you appear determined to mislead those reading?

Comment: To be clear, I'm withholding judgement on this particular situation for the time being; I'd much prefer y'all worked this out among yourselves, because that's the only way you're ever gonna have a working community here. My comments are intended to help you improve your post and generate a productive discussion; take them or leave them.

Comment: @Shog9, Nice if we decide a time & chat room to have free discussion (it's late in India right now). You say: *"you have to be open and honest"* -- We feel that the deleting Mod is not open enough to accept mistakes. *"closing paragraph"* -- which? *"you accused another moderator but ignored the rationale"* -- what rationale? Out of my 5 answers, I haven't objected for 2 (even though they met standard). Out of remaining 3, 1 got undeleted. But I don't want to come to meta every time, asking for justice. Better to have a Mod, who understands policy. 2 quitting Mods actually understand it well.

Comment: Have the discussion on meta, @iammilind. There are more people interested than those with time to hang around in chat. If you want moderators - and the 20 or so other members who can delete - to agree on a policy for deletion, it has to be something that's explicit and easy to find, not a bunch of assumptions and some scattered chat conversations. How do you get that? Well, you start by discussing *every controversial deletion* until y'all can hammer out an agreement. There's no "shortcut" to that.

Comment: @Shog9, Asked for chat bcoz, (1) [Delete hammer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/314/1049) is already discussed long back. But strong disagreement on its implementation among some users & a Mod. Many meta posts, but still a deadlock (2) I personally feel obliged Not to fill up the comment section under any post. In the room where you chatted recently, we many useful discussions. --- BTW, "withholding or not fixing" this issue will also fix this. :-) Until this Mod issue, I won't participate. Other handful users will also be silenced gradually. None to complain. Site will run smoothly.

Comment: Look, @iammilind... Every other site discusses deletion regularly. Stack Overflow debates it daily. This isn't one of those things like picking a name or tagline, where you discuss it once and it's over; the notion of what should be kept and what should be deleted gets adjusted and refined over and over again as the site grows and matures. Most of my early posts are long ago deleted; heck, there's one site where almost ALL of my posts are deleted, even though I earned over 7000 rep off of them. And that's **good** - that means the site didn't stagnate. So... Keep talking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upvoted the question.

**Yes, we need to change the moderators**. I have made my objections to the current state of moderation clear many times over. We need more maturity, more **objectivity**, standard set of moderation rules that are uniformly applied, **less bias** and less random actions based on personal agendas. We also need the moderators not to act in an "us vs them" fashion when it comes to responding to contentions from users.

Comment: I have suggested your name for Moderation in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34172352#34172352), where many prominent users are active right now. Would you able to take the responsibility if given a chance or still not interested as you stated [last time](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/441/change-the-moderators-of-hinduism-se-site#comment1295_441)?

Comment: @iammilind Milind. Thank you for your confidence in me. However, I think yourself and sv are ideal for this task. Not me :-)

Answer (score 6):

1. Talking about deletion of answer:

   The nature of your answer is quite different to that of question. Questioner is looking for whether one should buy or rent a house according to Scripture which can be answered by Dharma Shahstra scriptures that guide the way of living.

   Whereas you're answer is about explaining how the question doesn't matter to one who focus on considering towards liberation with quoting what Jnana (Knowledge) and Ajnana (Ignorance) is. And concluded that anything of buying or renting is same for who thinks according to *your* expected spiritual level!

   So, you've handled question in different way with respect to what has may asked in question. Though you thinking may be right but this is **not** how answering does work.

   The following line sounds irrelevant or opinion only:

   > Having own house & car might be part of American Dream. But predominantly in other developed nations such as Germany & Netherlands, people rent homes & rent cars, respectively.

   Which I think need to avoid or eliminate.

   > If you think the question is opinion-based or off-topic, the **correct** procedure is to vote to close it. – Keshav Srinivasan♦ 3 hours ago
2. Talking about changing moderators

   Well, this clearly sounds about Keshav Srinivasan. I've pointed out such issue to him in my [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/674/277). He sounds correct in your case and I don't think he is mostly wrong. I don't believe moderator targets some people etc. Moderators may (or expected) **rarely** be wrong which is not the issue.

   You may find [Voting to have Keshav Srinivasan take a sabbatical as a moderator](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/361/277) already present similar to your this question. Which is [answered](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/362/277) by him.

   Though, in any case, if you feel something is going wrong with you, following posts can be helpful for you:

   - [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/260388)
   - [Could we please be a bit nicer to moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156122/260388)

   And/Btw, you can directly [contact](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/contact) SE instead of complaining on meta.

Comment: On renting vs buying, you missed very 1st line of answer: **Anything of them.** That alone holds the answer on itself. Rest of the sentences explain why I felt so. The scripture on "house" is also quoted. I never said "one should focus towards liberation". What I told is, "**if** one is towards liberation". In any case the answer will have lot of debate before deletion, not this way. Imagine if someone asks you, if you love your father or mother, & you say both of them because both are your parents. And someone despise you for "lying". And then another 1 informs that your answer is wrong.

Comment: You have also missed the entire part of making choice of renting vs buying based on *SwaDharma*. Regarding mods being mostly wrong or right is not the concern here. The issue is, targeting certain users. Deleting well crafted answer but not looking at low quality answers already listed in the link. Chat room etc hasn't worked in past. You might be lucky to solve your issues.

Comment: @iammilind Just corrected it.

Comment: "discussing in chat-room may help" - I agree, but as I stated in [this comment](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/656/is-the-moderator-justified-in-deleting-this-answer#comment2200_657) the chat option on Hinduism.SE is only to 'listen' while they 'explain' their decision, not to reverse a mistake :( I don't understand why moderators here think they can never make mistakes! And that their word is "final" and using dictator-sounding words such "EOD" (end of discussion) etc. -- that's a very bad attitude for any moderator to have.

Comment: "discussing in chat-room may help" - another take on this. Why can't the moderator initiate a chat with the high-rep user before deleting an answer? Don't you think it's better than "Shoot first, ask questions later?"

Comment: Pandya, *"KeshavSrinivasan AnkitSharma is this ok? Just want to make sure my contribution may not harm mistakenly."* [By asking for approvals of moderators](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34135444#34135444) in chatroom, while answering a question which criticises their actions; You are making a joke of this question, by such answer. Can't you rely on yourself? @sv. do you really agree that this kind of  
"[discussing in chat-room may help](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34137409#34137409)" *"KeshavSrinivasan Feel free to fix/correct my answer if needed"*?

Comment: @iammilind I just wanted to give scope as well. I can relay only on self. Anyway nothing is modified in my answer except my own. (Or you can just ignore it).

Comment: Well from your comments, it's evident that there was an obligation about putting an answer which may or may not go against Mods. But it's purely your choice & freedom. Hence, I am not here to judge your intentions on that. Such things reduces the weight of this post. Also noticed that you have put some "American dream" related part from my answer as my personal opinion. That's not right. That's inspired by the post of verified quora user Alex Tabarrok: [What do economists think about buying vs renting a house?](http://qr.ae/THeJQE). Besides I personally know many people from NL, who rent cars.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**: Regardless of any other user becoming moderator, do you feel that we need a change in leadership or direction, on how things are done on Hinduism.SE?

**Yes, I think we need a change; bring in new moderators.** Particularly because we currently only have one moderator who's very active. Or maybe it's just me who thinks so because I don't see the other two moderators as active as the main one. I'm not even sure if there's a way to objectively determine who's active and who's not, e.g., how to know which mod. has worked on most flags?

I don't have a problem with only one moderator being very active, as after all, moderation on SE sites is a totally voluntary commitment. However, when there's a dispute, if the other moderators are also active and have a chat with the complaining user to understand the problem from the user's perspective, **without prejudice** and without blindly supporting the concerned mod's actions, that would be very helpful.

> But when unfair deletion or decision happens from another mod, they support it by remaining passive & not **reversing the decision**.

Even if you bring in a new moderator, I am not sure if the new moderator will so easily reverse the decision of another moderator if there is a disagreement between them e.g., undeleting an answer that was wrongly deleted. Imagine two 1K+ users getting into an edit-war over an answer rolling back the answer to a previous version. We definitely don't want moderators doing that. Also, just having a good rapport with another moderator shouldn't mean they start supporting each other's wrong decisions.

However, when there is a disagreement between 2 moderators, IMO, adopting a 'majority wins' policy by all the mods is a good way to resolve the dispute at hand. Also, for any mod, **there is no shame in reversing a bad decision**, instead of sticking to one's guns which is what I keep seeing here on Hinduism.SE. We often see a big invisible `"DO NOT QUESTION OUR ACTIONS"` banner being waved by the current moderators here and this is definitely not good for the site.

Also, I suggest current and future moderators to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39267) meta.SE post where a moderator gracefully accepts his mistake:

> [Account suspension for answering questions well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39267)

You might also want to look at question no. 11 from 2016 SO election [questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337571) and go over some of the answers:

> 11.
>   How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

Under the question someone commented:

> Also, we should stop shaming moderators in public just as I commented on a thread previously where I told that we should stop shaming other people by mentioning their names.

IMO, moderators here and everywhere need to get over this narrow-minded and shoot-the-messenger thinking and instead try to solve the real problem at hand by not getting too emotional about the fact that their actions are being called into question. **If you find yourself getting easily upset because someone questioned your actions** openly on meta, then, IMHO, you're not fit to be a moderator! If you find yourself regularly downvoting meta posts that question mods' actions, then, moderation is not for you! Such moderators should simply relinquish their posts! **Give up the moderation job to others who are more tolerant to criticism.** Accept that moderation is not for everyone and just move on!

---

Another reason why we need a new moderator is the way [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/559) meta post is handled by the current moderators:

> [Upvoted and accepted answer deleted by moderator](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/559)

I see that none of the current mods actually answered OP's question which received 5 upvotes so far. Instead we find two high-rep users trying to address OP's question when it really should have been the moderators doing it by way of a proper answer. And let's not try to 'answer' questions in 'comments' or 'chat'. Why shouldn't the mod write a proper answer first, then invite comments on it from OP and other users?

Another meta post which hasn't received a single answer from the mods:

> [Moderators should give time & scope of discussion before deleting a post for active users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/513)

Comment: Downvote w/out reason? Excellent! :)

Comment: I agree with moderator should consider to reverse a bad decision and should answer the questions you've mentioned.

Comment: Liked this detailed answer very much. Most points are agreeable. Only small change of opinions I have here are: (1) A new Mod **should** reverse bad decisions of another Mod. Let this happen once to put a good check on unfair practices. Later being 2 responsible Mods, there won't be delete-undelete like edit-wars. I also know that, you too support reversing bad decisions. (2) Evaluation of comment about criticism is perfectly presented. But it might be taken wrongly by novice users as direct opposition. --- With your answer being my favourite, I have accepted moon's answer, which is clear cut.